# Geocoder force geocode on records in database with Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-geocoder

I've had an address table in my database for some time now, and recently have come across the Geocoder gem (sweet gem). Anyway, I've edited my model to include both the latitude and longitude columns, as well as specify what each record is supposed to be `geocoded_by`, so now I would like to simply geocode all of the addresses in the table now that currently have nil latitudes and longitudes.

I thought I had figured it out with the rails console, simply by running the command:

```
    Address.all.each{ |address| address.geocode }
```

This returns each entry with a filled in latitude and longitude column, however upon inspection of the individual elements afterwards - they still have nil latitudes and longitudes (i.e. the records are not actually being updated). I thought maybe `address.geocode!` would work, but that returned a `NoMethodError`.

This has got to be a simple one, but it seems I'm just inexperienced enough to not know what it is... aaaand with a little more tinkering I figured it out:

**Solution**

```
    Address.all.each{ |address| address.update_attributes(latitude: address.geocode[0], longitude: address.geocode[1]) }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply performing

```
    Address.all.each{ |address| address.geocode }
```

Does not actually change the records in the database.

**Solution**

Needed to use `update_attributes`:

```
    Address.all.each{ |address| address.update_attributes(latitude: address.geocode[0], longitude: address.geocode[1]) }
```

There may be quicker solutions out there embedded within Geocoder, but this was a quick solution to the problem, hope it helps others!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

geocode a single record:

```rb
address = Address.first
address.geocode
address.save
```

geocode all:

```rb
Address.all.each { |address| address.geocode && address.save }
```